# Flurry ads - Ad request to server failed

Tags: flurry

I've seen many open issues on Flurry's ad network not displaying any ads, none of them were addressed. I keep on receiving the following error, constantly, no matter what I do:

```
Error Domain=FlurryAds Code=117 "FlurryAds: Ad request to server failed." UserInfo=0x7fbf7e605000 {NSLocalizedDescription=FlurryAds: Ad request to server failed.}
```

Has anyone experienced this and was able to solve this issue? Anyone on the Flurry team monitoring Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely possibilities are that we either do not have an ad to fill in your geographic location or there is a problem with your Flurry integration.

You can test the first possibility by VPN to the US and see if you get ads.

Otherwise please send the following information to support@flurry.com

1) The API key for this project found under Manage -> App Info
2) SDK version
3) Adspace name
4) A code snippet where you fetch the ad
5) The corresponding output to your console logs

Comment: how is your fill rate in the middle east?

Comment: It depends upon what type of ad and which country. Are the ads RTB (banner, interstitial) or Gemini native / video ads? Send this and the above info to us and we'll look into it. support@flurry.com